# Multicolumn amsmath's align environment on a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, amsmath, multicol

I make a presentation for my students. On a frame I would like to break an align environment into two columns. The columns are visibly made, but the whole equation list is in the first column. Is there a solution for this or I shall use other multicolumning package?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{A racionális kitevő tulajdonságai}

        \pause
        \begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
                Legyen $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ és $q\in\mathbb{Z},\,|q|>1$. Akkor
                \begin{equation}
                        a^{\frac{p}{q}}=\sqrt[q]{a}^p.
                \end{equation}
        \end{alertblock}\vspace{-3ex}
        \pause
        \begin{exampleblock}{Permanencia-elv}
                Egy művelet kiterjesztésekor a művelet tulajdonságai a korábbi halmazon továbbra is érvényesek kell legyenek.
        \end{exampleblock}
        \pause
        \begin{block}{Tétel}
                Az alábbi azonosságok érvényesek minden $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$ és $m,n\in\mathbb{Q}$ szám esetén:
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                        \begin{align}
                                a^m\cdot a^n&=a^{m+n}\\
                                \frac{a^m}{a^n}&=a^{m-n}\\
                                a^m\cdot b^m&=(a\cdot b)^m\\
                                \frac{a^m}{b^m}&=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m\\
                                \left(a^m\right)^n&=a^{m\cdot n}
                        \end{align}
                \end{multicols}
        \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer has its own column mechanism, which allows you to place two `align` environments side by side:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<4>
        \frametitle{A racionális kitevő tulajdonságai}

        \pause
        \begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
                Legyen $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ és $q\in\mathbb{Z},\,|q|>1$. Akkor
                \begin{equation}
                        a^{\frac{p}{q}}=\sqrt[q]{a}^p.
                \end{equation}
        \end{alertblock}\vspace{-3ex}
        \pause
        \begin{exampleblock}{Permanencia-elv}
                Egy művelet kiterjesztésekor a művelet tulajdonságai a korábbi halmazon továbbra is érvényesek kell legyenek.
        \end{exampleblock}
        \pause
        \begin{block}{Tétel}
                Az alábbi azonosságok érvényesek minden $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$ és $m,n\in\mathbb{Q}$ szám esetén:
                \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                  \begin{align}
                          a^m\cdot a^n&=a^{m+n}\\
                          \frac{a^m}{a^n}&=a^{m-n}\\
                          a^m\cdot b^m&=(a\cdot b)^m
                  \end{align}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                  \begin{align}
                          \frac{a^m}{b^m}&=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m\\
                          \left(a^m\right)^n&=a^{m\cdot n}
                  \end{align}
                \end{column}
                \end{columns}
        \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]